# PHP PDO error syntax

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, server

Can someone help me:

[image]

I got error when i write this

```
$check = $db->prepare("SELECT email FROM user WHERE email = ?");
if($check->rowCount() == 1){
    $error = "<div class ='text-danger'> Email Telah Digunakan </div>"; 
} else {
    $code = rand();
    $status = 0;
    try{
        $query = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO users(first_name,last_name,email,password,gender,code,status) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,)");
        $query->execute([$first_name,$last_name,$email,password_hash($password,PASSWORD_DEFAULT),$gender,$code,$status]);   
    }
    catch(PDOException $e){
        echo"error:  " .$e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to `execute` and `bind` before you `count`.

Comment: You have a `,` at the end of your `VALUES()` without something after it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so you have a `,` at the end of your `VALUES()`'s list without something after it, which would lead to such syntax error. Here is the fixed version:

```
$check = $db->prepare("SELECT email FROM user WHERE email = ?");
if($check->rowCount() == 1){
    $error = "<div class ='text-danger'> Email Telah Digunakan </div>"; 
}else{
    $code = rand();
    $status = 0;
    try{
        $query = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO users(first_name,last_name,email,password,gender,code,status) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
        $query->execute([$first_name,$last_name,$email,password_hash($password,PASSWORD_DEFAULT),$gender,$code,$status]);
    }
    catch(PDOException $e){
        echo "error:  " .$e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

You where also missing a closing bracket for the `if` statement. Or maybe you copied wrongly. I've not actually checked full functionality, just the syntax errors I could find.

**A small tip**

If you format your code properly, you can find syntax errors *a lot* easier. A good code editor also helps.